# Flurry enableAppCircle() method undefined

Tags: java, android, sdk, import, flurry

this may be more of a library importing issue.

I have the Flurry SDK in my android java project. The latest version of FlurryAgent.jar is in my libs folder. (version 3.0.5)

Some methods work, such as `startSession` and `logEvent`, but other methods that the flurry docs say should exist are not within the SDK.

ie. enableAppCircle() is undefined.

Could this be possibly imported wrong or incompletely? some methods do work and log events on the Flurry web console.

How can I get the Appcircle methods

I am using Eclipse

Comment: documentation incorrect? What does the build output say? Did you clean the project after **importing** the library?

Comment: yes, I cleaned the project after importing the library. As mentioned, some methods within that library do work and do report application specific information to the Flurry servers.  Flurry's documentation says that `enableAppCircle()` method should be in the SDK yet my IDE is saying it is not.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it using ant on the command line? Does it report that `enableAppCircle` is missing or "unknown"... if not, and compiles happily, its the IDE that probably needs a "reboot" :)

Comment: How are you importing it and how are you trying to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flurry SDK v3.x for Android contains all the existing Flurry Analytics functionality as well as the new Advertising functionality. AdUnity is contained in the same JAR file that contains the Analytics libraries so no additional libraries are required. Also, the method enableAppCircle() is no longer present in this SDK. You just need to initialize and request ads inside your code. The integration instructions are available inside the SDK folder. Alternatively, you may refer to the support page for more details: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android. (Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: yeah, the instructions on the AppCircle tab for publishers are completely different. Not the first time I've seen something like that with you guys, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Updated instructions will soon be uploaded under the AppCircle tab. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: new question, can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028123/flurry-ads-kill-my-android-service-and-widget-views

Comment: I've written to our Engineer to take a look at it. Thanks for bringing it to our notice!